# Create an ontology for a simple mathematical ques

Tags: java, math, ontology, owl-api, protege4

I want a help to create an ontology for a simple mathematical question in protege.
Question is like this,

"There are 5 boxes with 8 pencils, 6 boxes with 2 pencils, 4 boxes with 3 pencils.How many pencils are there?"

The quantity and the name of the Items can be changed. I just want a help, how to get a pattern to represent this question in protege.

This is a part of my ontology. But it doesnt represnt the quantity with respect to the each item quantity sets.

```
<!-- Item1 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item"/>
    <Item1_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">PencilBox</Item1_Name>
    <Item2_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Pencil</Item2_Name>
    <include rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- Item2 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item"/>
    <Item2_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Pencil</Item2_Name>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: Do you want to use a reasoner to answer the question, or do you want just to be able to represent it? For representation, you should be able to do it with an object property (`has_pencil`) and two classes `Pencil` and `Box`, where you'd have fifteen Box instances and 64 Pencil instances (as one possible representation). Using a reasoner to solve this question would require a much more complex model, I think - if I remember correctly, this could be undecidable.

Comment: No I just want to represent the questions in an Ontology, not to provide the answers. (But ontology should be able to represent in the way that one can answer it.) But answering is not needed for me )Actually what I want is to represent the ontology for this type of(patterns) questions.

Comment: 1. Sunil has 12 pencils. He gave 6 pencils to his brother. How many pencils does Sunil have?
2.There are 23 students in class. Each student has to be given 04 books. How many books are needed?
3. A row conations 15 chairs. How many chairs are there in 08 rows?
4. Box contains 36 biscuits. If a child is given 6 biscuits. How many children can get biscuits.
5.There are 4 boxes containing 6 pencils each and 3 boxes containing 8 pencils each. How many pencils are in all 7 boxes?

Comment: @Ignazio, So that I cannot create classes using the question contents(item names). It should be represent in a way that all those type of questions(patterns) can be represent in one ontology.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of the ontology with instances.

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item"/>
    <Item1_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Box</Item1_Name>
    <Item1_Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">4</Item1_Quantity>
    <Item1_Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">5</Item1_Quantity>
    <has rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- Item2 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item"/>
    <Item2_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">pencils</Item2_Name>
    <Item2_Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">3</Item2_Quantity>
    <Item2_Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">8</Item2_Quantity>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```